# epoll: How to identify which fd is ready when using a table of structures having many fds

Tags: c, epoll

I have the following structure:

```
struct myfds_for_nic {
    int fd1;
    int fd2;
    int fd3;
    int fd4;
    int fd5;
    netinfo *nic_info;
};
```

I have a an array of such structures.

```
struct myfds_for_nic nic_table[1000];
```

Each structure has 5 fds and I have 1000 such entries. I want to add all those fds into a single epoll instance. Because of the the fields of `struct epoll_event event`, I can either pass a fd or a pointer to my data. I am passing pointer to my data as show below

```
event.data.ptr = entry;
event.events = EPOLLIN;
epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, entry->fd3, &event);
```

During the epoll_wait, when one of the fds has an event, I will only know which entry it is but how do I find out which fd (out of 5 fds) under the entry is actually readable/writable?

Comment: Well with the code you show you *only* add `fd3` so it should be pretty simple. Otherwise, if you actually add multiple descriptors from the structure, you either have to rethink your design, or simply check which of the structures descriptors match the descriptor of the event.

Comment: Keep this structure 8-byte aligned and use lower 3 bits of the address to store fd index. On 64-bit systems upper 16-bit of any pointer are not used - you can use them too.

Comment: @Ivan That is generally bad advice, and is *highly* platform, OS and compiler dependent.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude With C11 (`_Alignas`) it is completely portable and is a very good idea. And is also used very often.

Comment: So, you'll have no problem enlightening us as to what C11 changed to make it "completely portable"?

Comment: @underscore_d Added `_Alignas`. Before that you would have to use compiler-specific attribute which is still very portable as one is always available. Other than that it is perfectly portable and is guaratneed to work on any POSIX system.

Comment: `event` does allow passing custom data, and as per documentation the same data pointer is passed back in `epoll_wait`. So why cant that be used?

Comment: event allow either passing fd or data but not both. I.E its a union. I addressed this by adding an index to the above structure and am I accessing the global array table using this index present as a part of event data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event allows passing custom data. You can use this in one of the following ways:

1) pass the address of the FD member in the struct and then use pointer arithmetic to figure out which structure in your array the address belongs to and which FD. By aligning the struct on a 2^n boundary you can use bit shifts and masks or this.

2) Encode the index of the structure and index of the FD in a single int, e.g. index * 5 + fd. Getting the index and fd back from that is trivial.

3) Allocate an extra `struct { struct myfds_for_nic * nic; int num_fd; }` for each FD you add, fill it out and use it's address as data for the event.

Option 2 might be the easiest to understand while option 3 is the most generic.